# podman on macOS build selenoid but failed with permission issue

Tags: docker, containers, podman, selenoid

I'm setting up the selenoid on macOS with podman instead of docker.Below issue happened when connect to the sock.

```
Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Post "http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.12/containers/create": dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied
```

For the podman, i use homebrew to install it

```
Client:       Podman Engine
Version:      4.2.0
API Version:  4.2.0
Go Version:   go1.18.5
OS/Arch:      darwin/amd64

Server:       Podman Engine
Version:      4.2.0
API Version:  4.2.0
Go Version:   go1.18.4
OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
```

Then start the podman machine and shows below information, also installed the mac helper.

```
Starting machine "podman-machine-default"
Waiting for VM ...
Mounting volume... /Users:/Users
API forwarding listening on: /var/run/docker.sock
Docker API clients default to this address. You do not need to set DOCKER_HOST.

Machine "podman-machine-default" started successfully
```

This is the system connection list

```
podman system connection list
Name                         URI                                                               Identity                                   Default
podman-machine-default       ssh://core@localhost:51953/run/user/509218199/podman/podman.sock  /Users/xxx/.ssh/podman-machine-default  false
podman-machine-default-root  ssh://root@localhost:51953/run/podman/podman.sock                 /Users/xxx/.ssh/podman-machine-default  true
```

I can start the containers successful, but when use it to create driver section. the permission error happen.
I'm not sure if I missed any setup for the podman and cause this error, can someone give the advices?

Comment: Probably you have to add yourself to some group that owns this socket, e.g. `podman` - just check socket owner. Also Selenoid was never tested against podman.

Comment: @vania-pooh
I tried, this one ssh://core@localhost:51953/run/user/509218199/podman/podman.sock is my account, this one ssh://root@localhost:51953/run/podman/podman.sock is I started the podman machine as root. does it mean I shouldn't start machine as root?

Answer (score 0):

i think that you solved the problem but incase some one will have this again.
My solution for this was to erase podman and install docker in my rhel VM
read this for more info:
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/rhel/

they have wrong url so after doing all the steps write this command

```
sudo sed -i -e 's/baseurl=https:\/\/download\.docker\.com\/linux\/\(fedora\|rhel\)\/$releasever/baseurl\=https:\/\/download.docker.com\/linux\/centos\/$releasever/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/docker-ce.repo
```

Hope it help ! :)